# Can't add an IntPtr and an Int

Tags: c#, int, addition, intptr

I have this lines in C# Visual Studio 2010:

```
IntPtr a = new IntPtr(10);
IntPtr b = a + 10;
```

And it says:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.IntPtr' and 'int'.

[MSDN says that this operation should work.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.op_addition.aspx)

Comment: Is your project targeting .NET 4?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are targetting .net 4 then your code will work.

For earlier versions you need to use [`IntPtr.ToInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.toint64.aspx).

```
IntPtr a = new IntPtr(10);
IntPtr b = new IntPtr(a.ToInt64()+10);
```

Use `ToInt64` rather than `ToInt32` so that your code works for both 32 and 64 bit.